# How to programmatically assign touch screen to display in Windows?

Tags: windows, input, touch, settings, tablet

In Windows there is a panel called Tablet PC Settings which allows a user to configure which display will be assigned to a determined touch input.

I would like to programmatically do this but can't find an API to do it. Maybe I have not crossed myself with the rights documents yet.

Does anybody knows if this API is public an can be used for 3rd party developers?

Thanks

Comment: Any news on this topic?